# Do quest items have weight? 

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have a ton of the [Unusual Gem](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Unusual_Gem#Unusual_Gem) items stuck in my inventory.
It was a long evening, and I have lost the chance to go back to a save point before I picked up the [No Stone Unturned](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:No_Stone_Unturned) quest.

These stupid rocks are taking up 12 "pounds" in my inventory and I have no interest in completing it.

Is there any way for me to drop this quest or lose the super-heavy quest items?  A game mod? A dirty-letter campaign to the game designer?  Voodoo witchcraft? Anything?

Comment: actually quest items, despite saying they have a weight, actually has no weight.  Anyway, are you on the PC or a console?

Comment: As mentioned in my post, I am playing on a PS3 console.
Are you sure they have no weight???  That's great news!  Because I couldn't drop the item, there was no way for me to test.  Thanks!

Comment: yes, you can easily check though by finding a container and dumping all your stuff there and then seeing what your encumbrance is

Comment: @yx If you would post that as an answer, I will accept it. It is not exactly what I was asking, but it solves my concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the quest items page on the [skyrim wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Quest_Items_(Skyrim)):

> While quest items do display a weight, they do not use up the inventory's available space.

So you don't have to worry about quest items sitting in your inventory :)

Comment: You are indeed right, would you be willing to edit my "answer" into yours for PC users that might stumble upon this question? In that case I'll delete my answer :)

Comment: @assile there's no need, your answer does provide additional info so there's no reason why it shouldn't be left there

Comment: Ok, in that case we'll do it that way :)

Answer (score 2):

You are indeed stuck with the gems without the use of console or mod if you cannot complete the quest.

There may be a mod that makes them weightless (I cannot search the steam workshop myself the coming few days).

And as @yx suggested, you can use the console if you are on PC with the command `player.removeitem 0009dfbb 24`.

However, since you seem to have 24 of them I'd suggest trying to turn the [quest](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:No_Stone_Unturned) in. I do not know about the 'not having weight' since they seem to weigh me down.

Comment: quest items have no weight, so no mods are needed see my comment above.  Besides, he's on PS3 so no mods or console available.